# I get error when I try to past list as argument to another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in this class I want two forward List **getpoints** to **Points** class, and I call **Points class** in line 27

> Points(
> sumation: getpoints,
> );
> But when run function ( sumation1 after press button) in class **Points** I got Error

> The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: iterator

```
class PointsFild extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PointsFildState createState() => _PointsFildState();
}

class _PointsFildState extends State<PointsFild> {
  List<double> getpoints = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 7,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "INSERT POINTS Player ONE",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  getpoints[0] = double.parse(value);
                  Points(
                    sumation: getpoints,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "INSERT POINTS Player TWO",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  getpoints[1] = double.parse(value);
                  Points(
                    sumation: getpoints,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit_sharp), onPressed: null)
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Class Points,
the function should run after put sumatin1() on press button X>>

```
class Points extends StatelessWidget {
  List<double> sumation;

  final String name1, name2;
  Points({this.name1, this.name2, this.sumation});

  double sum = 0;
  void sumation1() {
    for (double i in sumation) {
      sum = sum + i;
      print(sum);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("CALCULATIN POINTS"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [RowOne()],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Card(
                elevation: 5,
                child: Text(name1),
              ),
              Card(
                elevation: 5,
                child: Text(name2),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Card(
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("X"),
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              ),
              Card(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text("X>>"),
                  onPressed: sumation1,
                ),
                elevation: 5,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Text("Show result 1"),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Text("Show result 1"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Text("Show result HERE1"),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Text("Show result HERE2"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          PointsFild(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```